# How to get DynamoDB records in timestamp order

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoBD table with Partition key is `id` and Sort key is `timestamp`.

I want to get records with a `timestamp` == specific day with ascending order.
Unfortunately, every record has a unique random `id` so I cannot use `timestamp` as a sort key to get the data sorted.

I am thinking of using a global secondary index but it does not work.

My global secondary index:

- Name: timestamp-index
- Partition key: timestamp
- Sort key: None

My query:

```
options = {'IndexName': 'timestamp-index', 'FilterExpression': Attr('timestamp').contains(yesterday)}

scanner = table.scan(**options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.  Which are better and worse depends on your [record and query volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach).  A good solution for low query volumes might be very bad if applied to high query volumes.

For a solution that scales to high volumes, check out [design patterns for time series data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html) from the docs.

That multi-table design buys scalability at the cost of complexity.  If scaling is not a huge concern
and you have relatively few queries, you might get by with a single table design with a GSI:

```sh
GSI1PK (Date)       GSI1SK (Time)
2021-11-29          02:00:19.000
2021-11-29          05:11:33.000
2021-11-29          12:57:19.000
2021-11-30          03:33:41.000
2021-11-30          13:33:41.000
2021-11-30          20:33:41.000
```

You can query your Secondary Index with `GSI1PK="2021-11-30" AND GSI1SK>""` to get all records for 30 Nov.
Having Time as the GSI SK gives you the option to query with the day by hour: `AND GSI1SK begins_with("12")`.

By default, `query` sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, set the `ScanIndexForward` parameter to `false`.  `scan` sort order is, I believe, undefined.